# Delete a newly created file using shell script after 5 minutes

Tags: linux, shell, cron, scheduled-tasks

I am writing a **shell script** where I create a file `ABC.txt` in a path `/path/to/ABC/ABC.txt`.
Now I at the end of the script, I want to schedule a cron job to delete this file after 5 minutes (just once, not recurring).
I cannot ad `sleep` of 5 minutes in this script as it is being used by multiple users on server for multiple paths/files. And 5 minutes after the user executes this script the corresponding `file.txt` from respective path should get deleted.

What I read from a cronjob is you can trigger a script using `crontab -e` and then providing periodic notation of job and path to script `H/5 * * * * /bin/sh /path/to/ABC/ABC.txt`.

Can someone tell me how to schedule such functionality using cron. If there is a better way to do this please suggest.

Comment: Wouldn't be an `at` job more suitable? _cron_ is for periodical jobs, _at_ for jobs executed once. Another possibility is to detach the 'sleep and delete'  process from your script, by putting it in the background, i.e. `(sleep 5; delete ABC.txt) &`

Comment: wouldn't sleep induce extra cpu load for 5 minutes because parent process (script) isnt terminated? i am creating this script for multiple users so possibly 100s of users executing this script t the same time. would that be a bottleneck?

Comment: If would find out that a _sleep_ is implemented by a _busy loop_, I would reformat my hard disk and install an operating system which deserves its name (Linux, BSD Unix, .... ). The main disadvantage of the "sleep" is that if someone reboots the computer while the sleep is in progress, the file is not being deleted, while with `at` - at least AFIK, haven't used the command for ages - the deletion would  be done after the reboot. If this is an issue, you may want to ask this for the safe side at [su].

Comment: I implemented with `sleep 300` as it is in seconds. and it is working. I would update this with increased number of users soon. will read about `at` and update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using `at` command:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
script_path="$(realpath -s -- "$0")"
# start script
...
# end script
echo "rm -- \"$script_path\"" | at "now + 5 minutes"
```

**Using background process with sleep:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
script_path="$(realpath -s -- "$0")"
# start script
...
# end script
( sleep 300 && rm -- "$script_path" ) &
```

**Using parent `selfdestruct` process:**

Write a little script `selfdestruct` that looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
dt="$1"; shift
"$@"
( sleep "$dt" && rm -- "$1" ) &
```

and run your script with

```
$ selfdestruct 300 /path/to/script arg1 arg2 arg3
```